# Erro ao tentar acessar determinadas informações do banco

Tags: postgresql, delphi-7

Estou tentando acessar determinadas informações do meu banco de dados, porém está ocorrendo o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Trecho onde ao depurar o erro ocorre:

```
IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
IdHTTP.Port := 80;
IdHTTP.Connect(-1);
IdHTTP.Request.BasicAuthentication := true;
```

Comment: Já tentou utilizar breakpoints pra tentar onde o problema está?

Comment: Tua base tá conectada no momento que você dá open nessa query?

Comment: @Sorack Base? Como posso validar isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `Connect` do `IdHTTP` só funciona se você já tiver o endereço. Remova essa linha e adicione apenas se for colocar o endereço da URL a conectar.